# Repeated alarm is not accurate

Tags: java, android, eclipse, alarmmanager

I made an app which has a number picker ranging from 1 to 60 minutes, and I connected it to a repeated alarm manager. When I gave it a try, I noticed that it's not accurate sometimes, it either takes more minutes to work or less.

What could be the problem?

For the start button:

```
startB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (startB.isChecked())
            {
            Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, picker2.getValue());
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            setAlarm(calSet);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", startB.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
                timerHasStarted = true;

            }
        else
            {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", startB.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
                timerHasStarted = false;

            }
        }  
        });
```

For the alarm:

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
            targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), 
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(picker2.getValue()),
            pendingIntent);
}
```

Receiver:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         MediaPlayer m=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
         m.start();

    }
```

Comment: The problem is API19+

Comment: @DerGolem is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Yes, use `setWindow()`, for API Level 19+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Android OS is able to shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery consumption (since API 19). Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). I noticed delays up to a few seconds.

A pretty nice tutorial on alarms in general could be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: aww i see. Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Yes, use `setWindow()`, for API Level 19+

Comment: yeah but keep the following in mind: _For the rare app that has rigid time requirements—for example, the alarm needs to fire precisely at 8:30 a.m., and every hour on the hour thereafter—use setRepeating(). **But you should avoid using exact alarms if possible**._ A higher battery drain would be the result -> haters gonna hate...

Comment: I'd hate more a non accurate alarm.

Comment: I guess that depends on the purpose of your application :D